# Google cloud OAuth api verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm a bit confused if I need to get my app verified to use the Google OAuth api for accessing Google Fit data.

I haven't seen any warnings in the developer console or the documentation that the google fit api is a sensitive or restricted scope. The limit of 100 users with sensitive scopes has not gone up either. So I assume fit doesn't fall under these? Are there any plans to change the scope for fit in the future?

Since I haven't encountered any warnings so far, do I need to worry about getting my app verified? Would the only benefit be the ability to change the icon displayed in the consent screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OAuth Flow Google use to verify the app. Reading through [the docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization#user_authorization_flow), I found out that it uses the [Authorization (or Grant) Code Flow](https://github.com/koenbuyens/oauth-2.0-security-cheat-sheet#authorization-code-grant).

This flow require a frontend intervention (user has to interact by approving the app to access the data of his account). This means that you **should** make the app being approved, otherwise you won't have access to any data.

You also add another layer by using Android (if you use it), since it also require per-device permissions (using sensors and so on).

If Google docs are too hard to understand, you can have a look at Spotify docs. They implemented the OAuth 2.0 Code Grant Flow to access personnal data of their Web API.